# Spring Authoriztion Server Introspection API Credentials

Tags: spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server, spring-resource-server

I am trying to use Spring OAuth2 resource server and Spring OAuth2 Authorization server with opaque/reference tokens.

In order to verify the token, the resource server must call the authorization server's introspection api to get the token payload.

The introspection API requires valid credentials corresponding to a RegisteredClient in the authorization server's RegisteredClientRepository. The client simply needs to exist - it doesn't need any scopes / authorizationGrantTypes.

My question is this: what is the recommended way to get these credentials? Should I create a special RegisteredClient for the resource server to use?

My current approach is to create a default user with credentials that the resource server knows

```
    RegisteredClient defaultUser = RegisteredClient.withId(DEFAULT_USER_ID)
        .clientId(DEFAULT_USER_ID)
        .clientSecret("***")
        // an authorizationGrantType is required by the builder
        .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType("none"))
        .build();

    registeredClientRepository.save(defaultUser);
```

Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: How did you get the reference token?

Comment: Requests to the resource server include a token in the Authorization header. The tokens are generated by the OAuth2 authorization server

Comment: But how did you get it in the first place?

Comment: The token is supplied by the client as part of the request to the resource server. The client gets the token via an OAuth2 flow, e.g. client_credentials. The resource server needs to verify the token before serving the client's request